# Assign href of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign href of Anchor tag using JavaScript.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AnchorTRY.aspx.cs" Inherits="AnchorTRY" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

  <a id="anchr" runat="server"> </a> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Email"] == null && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uid"] == null)
        {
            document.getElementById("anchr").setAttribute('href', "User Login.aspx");
            document.getElementById("anchr").innerText = "Create Your Own Package";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("anchr").setAttribute('href', "Cities.aspx");
            document.getElementById("anchr").innerText = "Add to Your Package";
        }
    </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: can you check the console logs for errors?

Comment: What's not working? Is it server side or client side? If you run the JS in the javascript console of your browser does it work?

Comment: I have no idea what `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` is.

Comment: OK I want let the user to move to login page if he is not signed-in else he/she should move to another page. So if the above condition is satisfied then he should log-in first else he mudt move to another location

Comment: I think you need a better basic understanding of the server world and the browser world. Browser code has no access to server context. In addition, please take more care with writing your question. Actually, I don't even know what your question is, other than an implied "it doesn't work". If it doesn't work, how doesn't it work? What are the symptoms? What is the behavior? What did you try to fix the problem and what was the result, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you code to this,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function setHref() {
            var flag = <% 
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Email"] == null && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["uid"] == null)
            {
              response.write("true");
            }
            else
            {
              response.write("false");
            }
            %>;

            if(flag == true)
            {
                document.getElementById("anchr").setAttribute('href', "User Login.aspx");
                document.getElementById("anchr").innerText = "Create Your Own Package";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("anchr").setAttribute('href', "Cities.aspx");
                document.getElementById("anchr").innerText = "Add to Your Package";
            }
       }
   </script>
```

In the code we are assigning the output of your server-side code to a JavaScript variable 'flag' and according to its value JavaScript code will assign the href attribute.

And we have placed this code in to a JavaScript function, we will call it when document loads, so that it will change '`href`' of anchor properly otherwise the code couldn't access anchor tag before it loads.

Call the function in `body` tag like this,

```
<body onload="setHref();">
```

Hope it works, let me know if you want more help. Thank you.

Comment: Can You Please tell me the use of <% %> in the script

Comment: If you want to write server side code along with HTML and JavaScript on a page, you need to use `<% %>` tag.

Comment: Sir, I want to pass Query string along with ocument.getElementById("anchr").setAttribute('href', "User Login.aspx?prev="+  Request.QueryString["city"]"); Can You Please tell me how can i do this, i used it by using <%%>, and tried all i could do. There is an error that Uncaught ReferenceError: Request is not defined

Comment: For that take another javascript vairable and assign this value to it, then concat it with your url. like `var city = '<% response.write(Request.QueryString["city"]) %>';` and concat like `document.getElementById("anchr").setAttribute('href', "User Login.aspx"+city);`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="Index/MasterPage?modID=<%=Session["ProductID"]%> ">
```

can use like this directly we can assign session values to href